# \setindexprenote justified and index ragged

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indexing

I'm tidying up my book before going into print and have a tiny problem: The index should be \raggedright but the index preamble should be justified.

This is what I've got, but for obvious reasons the preamble is ragged as well:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Word\index{Aaaa}

\setindexprenote{\blindtext}
\footnotesize\begin{flushleft}
\printindex
\end{flushleft}

\blindtext                                                      

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The index prenote is printed when you call the `\printindex` command, so the prenote is inside the flushleft environment

Comment: You could try `\usepackage[justific=raggedright]{idxlayout}` and remove the `flushleft` environment

Comment: The solution of @leandriis works. when transporting it into my real world example i had to remove this command \AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\RaggedRight} as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the contents of the index ragged right while keeping the justified index prenote, you can use the option `justific=raggedright` of the `idxlayout` package es shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[justific=raggedright]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Word\index{Aaaa}

\setindexprenote{\blindtext}
\footnotesize
\printindex

\blindtext                                                      

\end{document}
```